# Is there a mysqlfiddle?

Tags: php, mysql, ide

I've grown quite fond of jsfiddle and how easy it is to use.

Does anyone know of something that works with mysql and maybe php mixed in?

Comment: I doubt it. JSFiddle works because it's all browser-side stuff.

Comment: @ceejayoz You can still do some sandboxing at the database level, but it does introduce some more complexity and risk.  But anyhow, I've done just that with my site http://sqlfiddle.com - check out my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be interested in my site: http://sqlfiddle.com.  I've built it only recently, but it does support a decent range of database types (including MySQL) and has gotten a fair amount of use lately here on StackOverflow (see the mention on the sql [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)).  You can build indexes, and views, and do nearly anything you would normally want to do within a database.  Be sure to check out some of the sample fiddles, or see how various other SO users are using it:

[MySQL query - optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984836/mysql-query-optimized) -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fde2/39

[Multilevel Users in the Database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973611/multilevel-users-in-the-database-table) -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0de1f/7

[How to compare a value with a csv value in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938335/how-to-compare-a-value-with-a-csv-value-in-mysql) -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b642c/4

I guess I should mention that one other potential useful feature for SO would be that each query displays its execution plan, so if multiple people submitted answers to a sql question, you could easily evaluate their efficiency and then upvote/accept accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Try [SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/).

It has some annoying limitations, like the inability to create views, but overall I find it very useful.  (Tip: `CREATE INDEX` also doesn't work, but you can still create indexes inside `CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: It'll do in a pinch. I also found through the FAQ on SQLize on online IDE http://ideone.com/

Comment: Whaddaya know, there's something for everything. +1 :)

Comment: BTW @IlmariKaronen - I've built a similar site - http://sqlfiddle.com - that does not suffer from those limitations.