# How to compare a value with a csv value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Table 1

```
id(int) |  name(varchar)
1       |  at,bat
2       |  cat,at,bat,mat
3       |  mat,cat
4       |  sat,bat
```

Table 2

```
id(int)  |  type(varchar)
1        |  at
2        |  mat
```

As you can see table1 contains csv strings. Now I need to fetch the `id`s from `Table 1` whose `name`s exist in `Table2` type field.

Is there any pure mysql query way of doing this? if not, what would be the most time efficient way of doing this in case of large record sets?

Comment: just to be sure, do you want to un-concat each `name` of `table1` into rows and do a `where table1.name=table2.type`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select distinct t1.id
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on find_in_set(t2.type, t1.name) > 0
```

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b642c/4

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a06c/7)

```
select a.ids as id1, b.ids as id2, a.name,b.type
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on find_in_set(b.type,a.name)
```