# mysql comma seperated string not working for in where in(myArray) by using procedure?

Tags: mysql

In Mysql procedure:

```
select  distinct org_fk from user where id
in(IdList);


idList="1,2,3"
```

It is only working for first value.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the `IN` operator to compare against a CSV string, only a CSV list of separate values.

But MySQL has a function `FIND_IN_SET` which might help here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT org_fk
FROM user
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, idList) > 0;
```

You may read more about `FIND_IN_SET` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

[Stack overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938335/how-to-compare-a-value-with-a-csv-value-in-mysql)