# Multilevel Users in the Database table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am having one table users in which I have one field 'id' and another field is 'parent id'. Also I have expected target field in the users table.

I am having list of users till the 8th level hierarchy. Where A is parent of B and B is parent of C and so on.

e.g

```
A   level 0
|
B   level 1
|
c   level 2
```

Now when I am looking for user A. I want to get the all the sub users using sql query 'expected target'.
i.e. When I use id = id of A then I can see the expected target of A,B,C etc.

If expected_targets for A, B and C are 1000, 500 , 200 respectively the output should be like :

```
id      parent_id        expected_target

A_id                        1000  
B_id        A_id            500  
C_id        B_id            200
```

Comment: Is this database structure "locked down"? I can't think of any performant way of doing this with standard SQL (7 level self joins is not something I'd suggest)

Comment: It looks like the kind of problem that the [ltree](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html) module is meant to solve

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson what's wrong with 7 self joins.. it's perfectly reasonable if the number of levels is guaranteed ;) but i don't understand what is the *expected target* - should the results be in rows or columns?

Comment: @deathApril this is one of the column in the users table. I want result as  id parent_id expected_target

Comment: expected_target being the **top / root parent**? e.g. `C_id B_id A_id`?

Comment: @deathApril Please find the question edited.

Comment: oh,, mysql does not support with and postresql does not support recursion inside with clause :(( i guess multiple joins would be the answer

Comment: Postgresql supports `WITH RECURSIVE` since version 8.4. To the OP: please show us the table definition.

Comment: @wildplasser i just could not manage to create a working one on SQL Fiddle

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: no need for 7 level of self joins. Just use a recursive query (at least in PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1):

this will do the job - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0de1f/7:

```
select u1.id, u1.parent_id, u1.expected_target
from users u1
left join users u2 on u1.parent_id = u2.id
left join users u3 on u2.parent_id = u3.id
left join users u4 on u3.parent_id = u4.id
left join users u5 on u4.parent_id = u5.id
left join users u6 on u5.parent_id = u6.id
left join users u7 on u6.parent_id = u7.id
left join users u8 on u7.parent_id = u8.id
where :A_id in (u1.id, u2.id, u3.id, u4.id, u5.id,
                u6.id, u7.id, u8.id, u8.parent_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET search_path='tmp';

DROP TABLE targets CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE targets
        ( id integer not null primary key
        , parent_id integer references targets(id)
        , expected_target integer
        );

INSERT INTO targets(id,parent_id,expected_target) VALUES
(1,NULL, 1000), (2,1, 500), (3,2, 200);


WITH RECURSIVE zzz AS (
        SELECT t0.id, t0.parent_id
        , 0::integer AS level
        , t0.expected_target
        FROM targets t0
        WHERE t0.parent_id IS NULL
        UNION
        SELECT t1.id, t1.parent_id
        , 1+zzz.level AS level
        , t1.expected_target
        FROM targets t1
        JOIN zzz ON zzz.id = t1.parent_id
        )
SELECT * FROM zzz
        ;
```

OUTPUT:

```
SET
DROP TABLE
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "targets_pkey" for table "targets"
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
 id | parent_id | level | expected_target 
----+-----------+-------+-----------------
  1 |           |     0 |            1000
  2 |         1 |     1 |             500
  3 |         2 |     2 |             200
(3 rows)
```

UPDATE: if you don't want *the whole tree, the true tree and nothing but the tree* but only a subtree part of it, you can of course change the conditions a bit:

```
WITH RECURSIVE zzz AS (
        SELECT t0.id, t0.parent_id
        , 0::integer AS level
        , t0.expected_target
        FROM targets t0
        -- WHERE t0.parent_id IS NULL
        WHERE t0.id = 2
        UNION
        SELECT t1.id, t1.parent_id
        , 1+zzz.level AS level
        , t1.expected_target
        FROM targets t1
        JOIN zzz ON zzz.id = t1.parent_id
        )
SELECT * FROM zzz
        ;
```

Comment: This query is good one but if I want to see the results from id 2, then how can I write this query. I tried WHERE t0.id = 2 instead of WHERE t0.parent_id IS NULL but the query just going on running without any output.

Comment: What do you mean by "the results for id 2"? Only id=2? (seems trivial) id=2; including children and grandchildren and complete offspring?

Comment: if I am giving id = 1 then I want expected_target value for all his childs, grand child and so on. Similarli if I giving id = 2 then I want the results for all childs, grandchilds and so on.

Comment: But the query not showing me any output as it goes into infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

As this is tagged with PostgreSQL:

```
with recursive users_tree as (
  select id, 
         parent_id, 
         expected_target, 
         1 as level
  from users
  where id = 'A_id'

  union all

  select c.id, 
         c.parent_id, 
         c.expected_target,
         p.level + 1
  from users c
    join users_tree p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select *
from users_tree
```

MySQL is not advanced enough to support this. There you'll need to do a self-join for each level.

Comment: This query is not able to complete as it goes on running.

Comment: @SuryawanshiManoj: then apparently you have some cycles in your data (an id pointing to a parent that points back to the id itself - maybe over several levels)