# MySQL query - optimized

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Is it possible to achieve this task with a single **MySQL** query?

Table **urls**. Fields {**id**, **url**}

**1, www.mysite.kom

2, mysite.kom**

3, anothersite.kom

Table **logs**. Fields {**id**, **url_id**, **group_type** - a number in the range of 1..10}

**1, 1, 4

2, 1, 4

3, 2, 5

4, 2, 5**

5, 3, 9

The result of the query in this example should be: **1** (mysite.com and www.mysite.com = 1)

**THE GOAL:**

Need to count all distinct urls recorded in **logs** table, but with a few conditions:

1) Urls with and without **www.** prefix, like **mysite.kom** and **www.mysite.kom**,
 should be counted as **1** (not 2).

2) Have **group_type** in the range of **4..6**

3) Now, any of these urls with **group_type 4..6**, which appear in the list of those with **group_type** lower than 4 - should be ignored and not counted at all.

**The SQL code:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TRIM(LEADING 'www.' FROM b.url))
FROM logs a
INNER JOIN urls b
ON a.url_id = b.id
WHERE (group_type BETWEEN 4 AND 6) 

----- and this condition below -----

AND TRIM(LEADING 'www.' FROM b.url)
NOT IN (
  SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'www.' FROM b.url)
  FROM logs a
  INNER JOIN urls b
  ON a.url_id = b.id
  WHERE (group_type < 4)
)
```

If my sql query is correct, can it be optimized (to look more compact)?

Comment: Can't you just run your query to see if it's correct?

Comment: You might also want to try this question on [codereview.se].

Comment: @Michael Mior Yes, I tested it and it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT trimmed_url
  FROM ( SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'www.' FROM urls.url) AS trimmed_url,
                MIN(logs.group_type) AS min_group_type
           FROM logs
           JOIN urls
             ON urls.id = logs.url_id
          GROUP
             BY trimmed_url
       ) t
 WHERE min_group_type BETWEEN 4 AND 6
;
```

But only you can judge whether it looks more compact to you, and only testing can determine whether it performs better.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS COUNT_QUES FROM urls u
INNER JOIN logs l
ON u.id=l.url_id
WHERE u.url NOT IN (SELECT A.url FROM 
(SELECT * FROM urls u
WHERE SUBSTR(u.url,1,3)!='www')A,
(SELECT * FROM urls v
WHERE SUBSTR(v.url,1,3)='www')B
WHERE A.url=SUBSTR(B.url,5,LENGTH(B.url))
) 
AND l.group_type BETWEEN 4 AND 6
AND u.id NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT u.id FROM urls u
INNER JOIN logs l
ON u.id=l.url_id
WHERE u.url NOT IN (SELECT A.url FROM 
(SELECT * FROM urls u
WHERE SUBSTR(u.url,1,3)!='www')A,
(SELECT * FROM urls v
WHERE SUBSTR(v.url,1,3)='www')B
WHERE A.url=SUBSTR(B.url,5,LENGTH(B.url))
) 
AND l.group_type < 4
)
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.URL_ID IS NOT NULL AND FLAG1 = 1 AND FLAG2 = 0 THEN TRIM(LEADING 'www.' FROM A.URL) END)
FROM URLS A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT URL_ID,
           MAX(CASE WHEN GROUP_TYPE BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FLAG1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN GROUP_TYPE < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FLAG2
           FROM LOGS
           GROUP BY URL_ID) B
           ON A.ID = B.URL_ID
```

Hope this works for you.Check this on SQLFIDDLE - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fde2/39

Comment: Note that you can replace `MAX(CASE WHEN GROUP_TYPE BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` with `MAX(GROUP_TYPE BETWEEN 4 and 6)`.

Comment: Yep.. the case statement can be removed.